# How to use Object.keys()?

Tags: arrays, json, for-loop, foreach, javascript-objects

I'm usually used to play with the Object.keys() function.
But this time, I'm having trouble to read the value of the properties by their name, for each object within the following JSON :

### The JSON

```
var myData = {
  "customNotes":{
    "2017/04/17":{
      "concernedDate":"April, 17, 2017",
      "notesList":[
        {
          "id":25,
          "title":"Note 25 Title"
        },
        {
          "id":51,
          "title":"Note 51 Title"
        }
      ]
    },
    "2017/04/14":{
      "concernedDate":"April, 14, 2017",
      "notesList":[
        {
          "id":53,
          "title":"Note 53 Title"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### The OUTPUT I Need

**What I Need is the following OUTPUT :**

```
    2017/04/17
    concernedDate: April, 17, 2017
    Number of notes: 2
    Notes list:
    - id: 25
    - title: Note 25 Title
    - id: 51
    - title: Note 51 Title
    - - - - - - - -
    2017/04/14
    concernedDate: April, 14, 2017
    Number of notes: 1
    Notes list:
    - id: 53
    - title: Note 53 Title
```

### My buggy JS Code

```
$(Object.keys(myData.customNotes)).each(function(iGroup){

    //Get Key/Val of each Group of notes
    var keyGroup = Object.keys(myData.customNotes)[iGroup];
    var valGroup = myData.customNotes[keyGroup];

    //Print Key (the date as a string)
    console.log(valGroup[0]);

    //Print Key Property ('concernedDate')
    console.log('concernedDate: ' + valGroup[0].concernedDate);

    //Print Key Property Length ('notesList')
    console.log('Number of notes: ' + valGroup[0].notesList.length);

    //Print List of notes
    console.log('Notes list:');

    //If the property exists
    if(valGroup[0].notesList){
        //For each item in 'notesList'
        $(Object.keys(valGroup[0].notesList)).each(function(iNote){

            //Get Key/Val For each note
            var keyNote = Object.keys(valGroup[0].notesList)[iNote];
            var valNote = valGroup[0].notesList[keyNote];

            //Print the properties of each note
            console.log('- id: ' + valNote.id);
            console.log('- title: ' + valNote.title);
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**es6**

```
Object.keys(myData.customNotes).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const date = curr;
    const concernedDate = myData.customNotes[curr].concernedDate;
    const numberNotes = myData.customNotes[curr].notesList.length;
    const notesList = myData.customNotes[curr].notesList.map(note => `- id: ${note.id} \n - title: ${note.title} \n\n`);

    return prev + `${date} \n ${concernedDate} \n Number of notes: ${numberNotes} \n Notes list: \n ${notesList} \n - - - - - - - - \n`;
   }, ''));
```

**es5**

```
Object.keys(myData.customNotes).reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    const date = curr;
    const concernedDate = myData.customNotes[curr].concernedDate;
    const numberNotes = myData.customNotes[curr].notesList.length;
    const notesList =        myData.customNotes[curr].notesList.map(function(note) { return  ‘- id: ‘ +  note.id + ‘\n’ + ‘- title: ‘ + note.title + ‘\n\n’;});

    return prev + 'date' +  '\n' + concernedDate +  '\n Number of notes: ' + numberNotes +  '\n Notes list: \n' + notesList + ' \n - - - - - - - - \n';
}, ''));
```

Comment: Hi @cheesenthusiast, Thank you. It seems my latest Firefox does not accept this type of syntax. It returns : `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` ? I'm not used to this modern `\`` and `=>` operators.. Could you use a more "classic" (and longer) approach ?

Comment: I just edited it to include ES5 too. The "`"s are for template literals, so you don't have to concatenate larger strings.

Comment: Thank you very much @cheesenthusiast : Both your ES6 and ES5 versions are working. In fact, there was a superfluous parenthesis at the end of the `reduce()` function that was causing the `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` error. :-) (I've edited your answer to make it 100% correct. AND MANY THANKS for explaining me the templating functions avoiding me to concatenate long strings : That's awesome !

Comment: Just a question : After having added some elements in my array dynamically, how would I proceed to sort the `myData.customNotes` by date ? And do the same for each sub-item (sort them by concernedDate) ?

Comment: Hmm, in JS you can't guarantee the order that key/value pairs in an object are stored in, so an array is your best bet for that! Arrays also have a built in sort method, that takes a callback that takes two args, compares them somehow, and returns the one you wish to return to the beginning. But if there are other factors that make you lean toward the object format, and you only need it sorted in one place, you could always map over object.keys of custom notes (returns array), sort that, and reduce back into an object

Comment: @AlexLaforge you could also put them in a temp array like so and keep your object intact:

Comment: Object.keys(myData.customNotes).sort((a, b) => a > b ? a : b).map(k => myData.customNotes[k]);

Comment: I have tried this, but it always return the exact same items in the exact same order ... that is very strange ? :-/ I have also tried `var tmparr = Object.keys(A1_Indicators.CustomNotes.customNotes).map(function(k) { return A1_Indicators.CustomNotes.customNotes[k];}); tmparr.sort(function(a, b) {return (a > b ? a : b);});`

Comment: (please see my sorting tests below)

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to thank @cheesenthusiast for its answer: **It works like a charm**, and you should definitely rely on it, wether it is in ES6 or ES5 !

In the same time, I've experimented by myself, and found **another working solution**, in a more *"classic loopy-style"* way of achieving **the same result**.

### Another working method (more classical)

So for those of you that want to have more control at every step of the script, Here is **another working way to do it** :

```
//WORKING
console.log('---START LIST---');

//For each GROUP OF NOTES
for (var item in myData.customNotes) {
    //Print GROUP OF NOTES key
    console.log(item);

    //Print GROUP OF NOTES properties
    console.log('concernedDate: ' + myData.customNotes[item].concernedDate);
    console.log('Number of notes: ' + myData.customNotes[item].notesList.length);
    console.log('Notes list: ');

    //For each NOTE
    $(Object.keys(myData.customNotes[item].notesList)).each(function(iGroup){

        //Get this Array item
        var keyGroup = Object.keys(myData.customNotes[item].notesList)[iGroup];
        var valGroup = myData.customNotes[item].notesList[keyGroup];

        //Print NOTE properties
        console.log('- id: ' + valGroup.id);
        console.log('- title: ' + valGroup.title);

    });
    console.log('- - - - - -');

}
console.log('---END LIST---');
```

Answer (score 0):

### SORTING

After having added some elements to my Object, I need to sort it by **KEY** (the date : example 2017/04/17).

But it always returns the same items in the same order, regardless of what I try :

```
//Creating an Array of SORTED values (Nothing works :-/)
var tmpArr = Object.keys(myData.customNotes).sort((a, b) => a > b ? a : b);
var tmpArr = Object.keys(myData.customNotes).sort((a, b) => Date(a).valueOf() > Date(b).valueOf() ? a : b);
var tmpArr = Object.keys(myData.customNotes).sort((a, b) => a.valueOf() > b.valueOf() ? a : b);
var tmpArr = Object.keys(myData.customNotes).sort((a, b) => a-b);


//Convert back the Array to an Object
var myData.customNotes = tmpArr.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  acc[i] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: I'm not around computer but you can try removing the callback passed to sort and just calling it like sort()

Comment: Sorry about syntax error earlier, confused w/reduce! Also forgot to mention you don't have to go through all of that reduce stuff if you're not mutating it and have access to it somewhere. Anyway this works for me: Object.keys(myData.customNotes).sort((a, b) => new Date(a) < new Date(b) ? -1 : new Date(a) > new Date(b) ? 1 : 0).map(k => myData.customNotes[k]);

Comment: @cheesenthusiast : Thank you : Thats works perfectly for Arrays :)
I have chosen to open a new post to be more specific about this sorting topic. The result is that I've end up with a satisfying solution allowing me to stick with an **Object**, without having to deal with an **Array**. FYI, it's available here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611392/sort-a-javascript-object-by-key-then-by-named-property