# Sort a Javascript Object by Key, then by named property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I am having trouble into sorting the following Object by KEY (DESC).
Then, sorting each item by the "notesList.id" property (DESC).

### Expected order

- "2017/04/17"
- "2017/03/14"
- "2017/02/30"

Then, for the "2017/04/17" notesList items, here is the **Expected order** :

- id:57
- id:48
- id:12

### The JS Object

```
var myNotes = {
  "customNotes":{
    "2017/04/17":{
      "concernedDate":"2017/04/17",
      "notesList":[
        {
          "id":48,
          "title":"Title 48"
        },
        {
          "id":12,
          "title":"Title 12"
        },
        {
          "id":57,
          "title":"Title 57"
        }
      ]
    },
    "2017/02/30":{
      "concernedDate":"2017/02/30",
      "notesList":[
      {
        "id":92,
        "title":"Title 92"
      }
      ]
    },
    "2017/03/14":{
      "concernedDate":"2017/03/14",
      "notesList":[
      {
        "id":92,
        "title":"Title 92"
      }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### The Script

```
//Convert the OBJECT to an ARRAY
var tmpArr = Object.keys(myNotes.customNotes);

//Sort (Not working)
tmpArr.sort((a, b) => a > b ? a : b);

//Convert back the ARRAY to an OBJECT
Object.keys(myNotes.customNotes).sort((a, b) => a > b ? a : b).map(k => myNotes.customNotes[k]);
```

What am I missing ? I thank you very much

Comment: I think one of the important things that you are missing, is that objects are not sorted. Unlike an array you cannot rely on them being in any particular order, if you need an order, then you will need to store them as an array of objects. Instead it is best to look up objects by 'key'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observe a few things that seem out of place in your code.

1. `tmpArr.sort((a, b) => a > b ? a : b);` returns a sorted version of tmpArr. it will not modify myNotes object.
2. `Object.keys(myNotes.customNotes).sort(...` will return an array of objects from myNotes.customNotes, and not an object that has the same structure as myNotes like you intended.
3. In the code above, you are not sorting notesList.

Suppose you want to to get an array, all you need is to fix your sort function and also sort your notesList in the map function. So your code should look like this:

```js
var myNotes={customNotes:{"2017/04/17":{concernedDate:"2017/04/17",notesList:[{id:48,title:"Title 48"},{id:12,title:"Title 12"},{id:57,title:"Title 57"}]},"2017/02/30":{concernedDate:"2017/02/30",notesList:[{id:92,title:"Title 92"}]},"2017/03/14":{concernedDate:"2017/03/14",notesList:[{id:92,title:"Title 92"}]}}};

var res = Object.keys(myNotes.customNotes)
  .sort((a, b) => a < b)
  .map(k => {   
    let currNote = myNotes.customNotes[k];
    currNote.notesList.sort((a, b) => a.id < b.id)
    return myNotes.customNotes[k];
});

console.log(res);
```

But, if you intend to keep the structure of myNotes, I would suggest that you use reduce function. See my code below:

```js
var myNotes={customNotes:{"2017/04/17":{concernedDate:"2017/04/17",notesList:[{id:48,title:"Title 48"},{id:12,title:"Title 12"},{id:57,title:"Title 57"}]},"2017/02/30":{concernedDate:"2017/02/30",notesList:[{id:92,title:"Title 92"}]},"2017/03/14":{concernedDate:"2017/03/14",notesList:[{id:92,title:"Title 92"}]}}};

// MY SOLUTION
var sortedNotes = Object.keys(myNotes.customNotes)
  .sort((a, b) => a < b)
  .reduce((acc, val, _, arr) => { 
    acc[val] = myNotes.customNotes[val];
    acc[val].notesList.sort((a, b) => a.id < b.id);
    return acc;  
},{});

console.log(sortedNotes);
```

Comment: Your second script is perfect, as my Object remains an Object (and not an Array). It works perfectly : Many thanks to you ! It is clear, and very helping. I really appreciate :-) I've marked your answer as the Solution, because... **it IS** ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**thenBy.js**](https://github.com/Teun/thenBy.js)

Like this

```
data.sort(
    firstBy(function (v1, v2) { return v1.name.length - v2.name.length; })
    .thenBy(function (v1, v2) { return v1.population - v2.population; })
    .thenBy(function (v1, v2) { return v1.id - v2.id; })
);
```

You can also sort by property name by using this library

Like this

```
data.sort(
    firstBy(function (v) { return v.name.length; })
    .thenBy("population")
    .thenBy("id")
);
```

Comment: Hi Anik, this thenBy.js library is similar to some sorting libraries and functions I've used a few times, and can only be interesting into sorting the items of my Object by `id`. But it does not seem to be able to sort my main objects by their Keys (the dates).

Answer (score 1):

Your [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function should return either zero, a positive number or a negative number. You are just returning the values. Also note that this will convert your `customNotes` into an array, since objects cannot be sorted. If you do not wish that to happen, you can maintain another key with a sorted array of the keys in `customNotes` and use this array to look up the values in `customNotes`. Another approach would be to use the new [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object. `Map` supports sorted keys.

Try this:

```js
var myNotes = {
  "customNotes":{
    "2017/04/17":{
      "concernedDate":"2017/04/17",
      "notesList":[
        {
          "id":48,
          "title":"Title 48"
        },
        {
          "id":12,
          "title":"Title 12"
        },
        {
          "id":57,
          "title":"Title 57"
        }
      ]
    },
    "2017/02/30":{
      "concernedDate":"2017/02/30",
      "notesList":[
      {
        "id":92,
        "title":"Title 92"
      }
      ]
    },
    "2017/03/14":{
      "concernedDate":"2017/03/14",
      "notesList":[
      {
        "id":92,
        "title":"Title 92"
      }
      ]
    }
  }
}

var myNewNotes = {};
myNewNotes.customNotes = Object.keys(myNotes.customNotes).sort((a, b) => {
  if (a < b) return -1
  else if (a > b) return 1;
  else return 0;
}).map(key => sorted(myNotes.customNotes[key]));

function sorted(note) {
  note.notesList = note.notesList.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.id < b.id) return -1;
    else if (a.id > b.id) return 1;
    else return 0;
  })
  return note;
}

console.log(myNewNotes)
```

Comment: Just noting that the return values don't have to specifically be -1, 1 or 0. It can be any negative number, any positive number or 0. This is useful when sorting numbers (simply return `a - b`).

Comment: Thank you very much : Yes, I know that **Objects** are not sortable, and that only **Arrays** are. However, the @D-reaper answer is much compact, and will suit my current needs. I keep your structure by my side for future needs, "in case of", because with Javascript, you never really know what type of data you will need to deal with one day or another ^!^ Many thanks